# How to version row entries in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a table that lists a bunch of salespeople and their information. entry date which is the date the data is entered, the expiry date is supposed to track when the data gets replaced, there is a version field, a serial autogenerated primary key and a bunch of other stuff.

```
entry date | expiry date|ver|key|no     |name    |location  | product
2019-02-25 | 2199-12-31 | 1 | 1 | SP001 | Toby   | Bogota   |C
2019-02-25 | 2199-12-31 | 1 | 2 | SP002 | Janet  | Chicago  |M
2019-02-25 | 2199-12-31 | 1 | 3 | SP003 | Chepe  | Sinaloa  |H
2019-02-25 | 2199-12-31 | 1 | 4 | SP004 | Emilio | Colombia |E
2019-02-25 | 2199-12-31 | 1 | 5 | SP005 | Epifano| Texas    |C
```

Let's take the first entry for example:

```
entry date | expiry date|ver|key|no     |name    |location  | product    
2019-02-25 | 2199-12-31 | 1 | 1 | SP001 | Toby   | Bogota   |C
```

I want when Toby gets moved from Bogota to Jamaica, instead of doing an update on his location, it creates a new row which will be a new version of the one above. So if we change this on the 26th, we'll have two rows like:

```
entry date | expiry date|ver|key|no     |name    |location  | product    
2019-02-25 | 2019-02-26 | 1 | 1 | SP001 | Toby   | Bogota   |C
2019-02-26 | 2199-12-31 | 2 | 6 | SP001 | Toby   | Jamaica  |C
```

A new row is created and given the next serial in line as the primary key. The old row expires as the new version is created with the updated columns. 
This way, we still have the old row in the db instead of updating over it.

I was trying to accomplish by using and UPSERT:

```
INSERT INTO testarea.salepersons_3(
        date_from, date_to, version, sp_s_key, sp_no, sp_name, sp_territory, 
        sp_product)
VALUES ('2019-02-26', '2199-12-31', 1, 1, 'SP001', 'Tobby', 'Jamaica', 
        'C')
ON CONFLICT (sp_s_key)
DO UPDATE 
SET date_from = '2019-02-26', date_to = '2199-12-31',version = version + 1 ,sp_no = 'SP001',sp_name='Tobby',sp_territory='Jamaica',sp_product='C'
where b.sp_s_key = 1
```

This will, however, do an update without saving the original version. 
All tips are appreciated.

Comment: That's a bad design. History should be maintained in a separate history table and not appended in the same table. You may do the update to main and insert into history in a single transaction or write an after update trigger to accomplish it.

Comment: My design is to then have that table as my histories table. I will then pick the first version and update it with the most recent change and push that to the final table that will only keep the latest changes but the original serial key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The little-known [“timetravel” extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-spi.html#id-1.11.7.45.6) brings row-level versioning to PostgreSQL databases.

> #### timetravel — Functions for Implementing Time Travel
>
> Long ago, PostgreSQL had a built-in time travel feature that kept the insert and delete times for each tuple. This can be emulated using these functions. […]

In [a 2014–2015 blog post](https://blog.myitcv.io/2014/02/25/row-level-version-control-with-postgresql.html), Paul Jolly explains how it's done:

- Enable the `timetravel` extension in the database.
- Define timestamp fields named `valid_from` and `valid_to`, on each table where you want this behaviour.
- When querying that table, if the current time falls within `valid_from` to `valid_to` (including if `valid_to` is `infinity`), the record is current.
- Define triggers to expire the validity of the current record, based on its identity (probably the primary key), when updating that record.

Comment: Great, this worked for me. Although am still interested on how one would build a logic for this outside of any functions